# Recover a standard, single-index data frame after using pandas groupby+apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I want to apply a custom reduction function to each group in a Python dataframe. The function reduces the group to a single row by performing operations that combine several of the columns of the group.

I've implemented this like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  "afac": np.random.random(size=1000),
  "bfac": np.random.random(size=1000),
  "class":np.random.randint(low=0,high=5,size=1000)
})

def f(group):
  total_area = group['afac'].sum()
  per_area   = (group['afac']/total_area).values
  per_pop    = group['bfac'].values
  return pd.DataFrame(data={'per_apop': [np.sum(per_area*per_pop)]})

aggdf = df.groupby('class').apply(f)
```

My input data frame `df` looks like:

```
>>> df
         afac      bfac  class
0    0.689969  0.992403      0
1    0.688756  0.728763      1
2    0.086045  0.499061      1
3    0.078453  0.198435      2
4    0.621589  0.812233      4
```

But my code gives this multi-indexed data frame:

```
>>> aggdf
         per_apop
class            
0     0  0.553292
1     0  0.503112
2     0  0.444281
3     0  0.517646
4     0  0.503290
```

I've tried various ways of getting back to a "normal" data frame, but none seem to work.

```
>>> aggdf.reset_index()
   class  level_1  per_apop
0      0        0  0.553292
1      1        0  0.503112
2      2        0  0.444281
3      3        0  0.517646
4      4        0  0.503290

>>> aggdf.unstack().reset_index()
  class  per_apop
                0
0     0  0.553292
1     1  0.503112
2     2  0.444281
3     3  0.517646
4     4  0.503290
```

How can I perform this operation and get a normal data frame afterwards?

**Update:** The output data frame should have columns for `class` and `per_apop`. Ideally, the function `f` can return multiple columns and possibly multiple rows. Perhaps using

```
return pd.DataFrame(data={'per_apop': [np.sum(per_area*per_pop),2], 'sue':[1,3]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select which level to reset as well as if you want to retain the index using `reset_index`.  In your case, you ended up with a multi-index that has 2 levels: `class` and one that is unnamed.  `reset_index` allows you to reset the entire index (default) or just the levels you want.  In the following example, the *last* level (-1) is being pulled out of the index.  By also using `drop=True` it is dropped rather than appended as a column in the data frame.

```
aggdf.reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)

       per_apop
class
0      0.476184
1      0.476254
2      0.509735
3      0.502444
4      0.525287
```

#### EDIT:

To push the `class` level of the index back to the data frame, you can simply call `.reset_index()` again.  Ugly, but it work.

```
aggdf.reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).reset_index()

   class  per_apop
0      0  0.515733
1      1  0.497349
2      2  0.527063
3      3  0.515476
4      4  0.494530
```

Alternatively, you could also, reset the index, then just drop the extra column.

```
aggdf.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)


   class  per_apop
0      0  0.515733
1      1  0.497349
2      2  0.527063
3      3  0.515476
4      4  0.494530
```

Comment: This seems to work well. Can you explain what's going on?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back, I can access `aggdf['per_apop']` just fine, but `aggdf['class']` raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: OH! you need the class back in the data frame as well.

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry about that!

Comment: The updated answer seems to work. All of this seems like ugly hackery (at least, in comparison to R's dplyr). Is there a more canonical way I should be doing this?

Comment: In this case no.  Using `.apply` to return a dataframe is an odd pattern which lead to where you are.

Comment: Hmm, should I have collected the modified groups in a list and concated them? This just seems like a kind of standard thing a person would want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Make your self-def function return `Series`

```
def f(group):
  total_area = group['afac'].sum()
  per_area   = (group['afac']/total_area).values
  per_pop    = group['bfac'].values
  return pd.Series(data={'per_apop': np.sum(per_area*per_pop)})
df.groupby('class').apply(f).reset_index()

   class  per_apop
0      0  0.508332
1      1  0.505593
2      2  0.488117
3      3  0.481572
4      4  0.500401
```

Comment: This seems to prevent me from returning more than one row per dataframe, both otherwise seems to work well. Can you explain why this switch from `DataFrame` to `Series` works as it does?

Comment: @Richard check the open issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9867, and groupby.apply always have the issue with inconsistent output

Comment: I don't appear to be able to return multiple rows for each group using this answer, which I realize was not an explicit part of the question (since edited), but is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a good answer, a suggestion: 
test `func` for `df.groupby(...).apply( func )` on the first group, like this:

```
agroupby = df.groupby(...)  
for key, groupdf in agroupby:  # an iterator -> (key, groupdf) ... pairs
    break  # get the first pair
print( "\n-- first groupdf: len %d  type %s \n%s" % (
        len(groupdf), type(groupdf), groupdf ))  # DataFrame
test = myfunc( groupdf )
    # groupdf .col [col] [[col ...]] .set_index .resample ... as usual
```